# 1972 Volkswagen Karmann Ghia - What is this part / portal on the body?

Tags: vw, part-identification, body

[image]

Curious as to what this circular port is on our 72 VW Ghia. There is a matching one on the opposite side. There appears to be a bolt immediately opposite on the inside panel but I've not attempted to take it off yet. I'm familiar with the little tow sockets that are often in the front / rear bumpers and this has a similar feel, but being on the rear driver and passenger sides I'm just not sure

Comment: I'm wondering if that's the lift point for the jack? This would be the type of jack which has a horizontal bar which you'd stick into a whole in the side of the vehicle. Not dealt with a Ghia before ... actually don't think I've ever seen one in person (well, close enough to inspect it, anyway).

Comment: I don't think my idea is right, but [this image](https://www.thesamba.com/vw/archives/manuals/8_72ghia/42.jpg) does show the little "hole" just near the jack point.

Comment: Car jack support point?

Comment: yes @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - in the Step 5 image you can see the same one to the right of the jack

Comment: Ah! I think that is an access plate to get to where the [torsion tube is located](https://www.thesamba.com/vw/gallery/pix/1375584.jpg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this video](https://youtu.be/PTGAs5Mi6wg), this is an access port to adjust the torsion bar on the rear suspension.

Comment: Correct, described on this page in the "Body" section....https://www.hemmings.com/magazine/hsx/2008/11/1967-69-VW-Karmann-Ghia/1719335.html

Comment: @Moab - Thanks for the confirmation ... much appreciated.